# MYSQL Join multiple column from same table

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get skill name for `skill1`,`skill2`, & `skill3` from the table2 by using Join.

It works fine when Im trying to get `skill1` alone. But, **1066 Not unique table/alias** error comes out when I try to get details for the next column.

---

**Table 1 (User table)**

```
======================================
ID  Name       skill   skill2   skill3
======================================
1   Ed           1       4       3    
--------------------------------------
```

**Table 2 (Skill details)**

```
=========================
ID  Skill Name
=========================
1   php
2   html
3   css
4   mysql
-------------------------
```

---

**This is what I expect to get:**

```
[name]    => 'Ed'
[skill1]  => 'php'
[skill2]  => 'mysql'
[skill3]  => 'css'
```

Here's my code, I'm using laravel:

```
DB::table('table1')
   ->join('table2', function($join)
    {
         $join->on('table1.skill1', '=', 'table2.id');
    })
    ->join('table2', function($join)
    {
         $join->on('table1.skill2', '=', 'table2.id');
    })
    ->join('table2', function($join)
    {
         $join->on('table1.skill3', '=', 'table2.id');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I would reorganize my tables first and introduce a third one linking a user ID to a skill ID. Then you are not limited to 3 (or the amount of skill fields in your user table).

Comment: @jeroen many to many relationship is not for the faint of heart though

Comment: Think about you have 3 joins and each could be joined User.skil(n) to the skill table by skill.id, hint : each join on user.skil(n) will have a table alias name. Now you can try and show all what you did

Comment: If you want to go this way, you need to pay attention to the error message: You need aliases for the table names in the different joins.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT U.Name AS Name, S1.Skill Name AS Skill1, S2.Skill Name AS Skill2, S3.Skill Name AS Skill3
    FROM table1 U
    JOIN table2 S1 ON (S1.Id = U.skill1)
    JOIN table2 S2 ON (S2.Id = U.skill2)
    JOIN table2 S3 ON (S3.Id = U.skill3)
```

Comment: Nice ... However turns out that the performance is very bad when using more than three joins.

Answer (score 2):

Same result as @erickmcarvalho query

```
SELECT Table1.usrname,
(SELECT Table2.skillname FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.skill1 = Table2.Id) As skill1,
(SELECT Table2.skillname FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.skill2 = Table2.Id) As skill2,
(SELECT Table2.skillname FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.skill3 = Table2.Id) As skill3
FROM Table1
```

Still causes 4 queries, would been better to restructurate tables

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right, but the JOIN is slightly faster though

Comment: there is nothing wrong with 3 subqueries. I think restructuring a table vs proper indexing of the subqueries to be a rather silly claim. Just make sure all the subqueries are being run on indexes and there should be no issues.